# Web service returns error “The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request”

Tags: web-services

I am calling Web Service in my windows application(Web service is in same project). It works fine when I use it with test database, but when I change database schema to QA in web Service. It gives me error " “The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request”

The web service is same but still gets error when I change schema.This is Web Service, not WCF service and I am using VS2010. I am not understanding what is happening wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I have debugged code and it throws the above error when I call web method.

Comment: I mean if you have debug and the web service code? From win app debugging jump to web service debugging.

Comment: Can't debug webservice code. When pressed F11 key where proxy calls web method, there itself it throws exception, whereas I am able to debug web service code when I set database to Test.

Comment: You have one solution with x projects? One of them is the web service and one the win app? If yes debug win app and then right click on web service project and then start new instance on debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, one of the values in the DTO which was passed to webmethod was having some bad data(say, memberid="H00001\0\0\0\0"). I corrected this value and assigned to DTO before passing to webmehtod. And it worked fine. Thanks kostas ch. and Salahuddin for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is error in paramters you supply to webpage (webservice) of website. Check what you supply in headers of your request object.